# Sort list dict by key of dictionary inside a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a data struct that below:

```
[
{
original_price: {
value: ""
},
promos: [ ],
local_id: "122863",
url: "link",
title: "abc",
current_price: {
value: 19.5
},
image: "link",
selections: {
color: "BLACK",
length: "",
size: "7"
},
store: "abc"
},
{
original_price: {
value: ""
},
promos: [ ],
local_id: "122863",
url: "link",
title: "abc",
current_price: {
value: 19.5
},
image: "link",
selections: {
color: "BLACK",
length: "",
size: "9"
},
store: "abc"
},
{
original_price: {
value: ""
},
promos: [ ],
local_id: "122863",
url: "link",
title: "abc",
current_price: {
value: 19.5
},
image: "link",
selections: {
color: "BLACK",
length: "",
size: "6"
},
store: "abc"
}
]
```

I try to sort it by 'size' key with code:

```
def order_size(self, raw_sizes): 
     for i in range(len(raw_sizes)):
         print i
         for j in range(i+1, len(raw_sizes)):
             #print raw_sizes
             if raw_sizes[j]['selections']['size'] < raw_sizes[i]['selections']['size']:
                 raw_sizes[j], raw_sizes[i] = raw_sizes[i], raw_sizes[j]


     #print raw_sizes
     return raw_sizes
```

But I can't. Please help me.
I expect result:

```
[
{
original_price: {
value: ""
},
promos: [ ],
local_id: "122863",
url: "link",
title: "abc",
current_price: {
value: 19.5
},
image: "link",
selections: {
color: "BLACK",
length: "",
size: "6"
},
store: "abc"
},
{
original_price: {
value: ""
},
promos: [ ],
local_id: "122863",
url: "link",
title: "abc",
current_price: {
value: 19.5
},
image: "link",
selections: {
color: "BLACK",
length: "",
size: "7"
},
store: "abc"
},
{
original_price: {
value: ""
},
promos: [ ],
local_id: "122863",
url: "link",
title: "abc",
current_price: {
value: 19.5
},
image: "link",
selections: {
color: "BLACK",
length: "",
size: "9"
},
store: "abc"
}
]
```

This list of dict in order that was sorted by dict key inside dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that a bubblesort? Really?

Anyway, there's no need to write your own sort function:

```
raw_sizes.sort(key=lambda d: d['selections']['size'])
```

Comment: I think the key func should be lambda d: d['selections']['size']

Comment: @PiotrHajduga thanks, changed - I wasn't able to check it in the interpreter because the original "dict" is not in Python syntax.

Comment: yeah, It is bubblesort. I try your suggestion but Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'size'. with sort function i can't access a key of dict inside dict

Comment: My edit above works for me, once I've converted your data to actual Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: thanks you for help. Please explain for me converted data to actual Python (I just beginner)

Comment: In Python (unlike, for example, Javascript), dictionary keys need to be quoted.